# Does there exist an integer $x$ satisfying the following congruences?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Does there exist an integer $x$ satisfying the following congruences?
>   $$10x = 1 \pmod {21} \\
> 5x = 2 \pmod 6 \\
> 4x = 1 \pmod 7$$

I was trying to do this by following way but failed to get an answer:-

At first rewrite the equation as:
$$\begin{align}10x = 1 \pmod 3 \tag{1} \\   
10x = 1 \pmod 7 \tag{2} \\   
5x = 2 \pmod 2 \tag{3} \\  
5x = 2 \pmod 3 \tag{4} \\     
4x = 1 \pmod 7 \tag{5}\end{align}$$
But equation $(1)$ and $(4)$, and $(2)$ and $(5)$ are same. So it becomes as:
$$10x = 1 \pmod 3 \\   
10x = 1 \pmod 7 \\
5x = 2 \pmod 2$$
 and now try to solve this by Chinese Remainder Theorem. But the answer does not satisfy. Is my process wrong?

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, no solutions exist.

Answer (score 4):

By the first equation $10x = 1 \pmod 7$, but then $20x = 2(10x) = 2 \pmod 7$, whereas by the last equation $20x = 5(4x) = 5 \pmod 7$.

A contradiction!

Hence no solutions exist.

The problem in your derivation seems to be that equation (2) and (5) are incompatible rather than equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

$(2)$ and $(5)$ are not the same. $(2)$ can be rewritten as $$10x \equiv 1 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad 3x \equiv 1 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x \equiv 3^{-1} \equiv 5 \mod 7,$$ whereas $(5)$ can be rewritten as $$4x \equiv 1 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x \equiv 4^{-1} \equiv 2 \mod 7.$$